# How to reset the user and login with correct permissions across many databases in AWS RDS

Tags: sql-server, iteration, amazon-rds

I have multiple databases in an RDS mssql database that all have the same user `sysuser` tied to a single login `sysuser`. When the program installs another db into the rds server, it can mess up the connection and permissions of the other tables. This means I don't always  know the exact name of the table but I know which tables not to affect (`tempdb`, `rdsadmin`, `msdb`, `model`, and `master`)

To fix this manually, I use SSMS (sql management studio) to drop all the `sysuser`s across the databases, go to the login properties of `syslogin`, map this login to all the appropriate databases, and ensure user has membership in the right roles (`db_datareader`, `db_datawriter`).

Now trying to do this with a script is being difficult because I'm not sure how to loop over the result of `master.dbo.sysdatabases` and affect them.

```
DECLARE @tables VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT
use [master]
@tables = select name from master.dbo.sysdatabases where NOT name='rdsadmin' AND NOT name='master' AND NOT name='msdb' AND NOT name='model' AND NOT name='tempdb'

?? for table in tables ??
BEGIN
    use [table]

    -- prevent dropping if it owns the schema
    ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::db_owner TO dbo
    DROP USER sysuser
    CREATE USER sysuser from login sysuser;
    ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER sysuser;
    ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER sysuser;
    ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER sysuser;
    GO
END
```

I know that looping isn't an idea in SQL server, but how might I achieve this?

UPDATE:

Trying to use `sp_MSforeachdb` has sometimes worked, but it not reliable. It seems to be dependent on which default database my user is logged into. I want to see if this might work better.

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb
@command1='IF ''?''
NOT IN (''rdsadmin'', ''master'', ''msdb'', ''model'', ''tempdb'')
BEGIN
    ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::db_owner TO dbo
    IF EXISTS(select 1 from sys.database_principals where name=''sysuser'')
        DROP USER sysuser
    CREATE USER sysuser from login sysuser;
    ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER sysuser;
    ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER sysuser;
    ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER sysuser;
END'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem with my updated code was it was missing `USE ?`. This was necessary and I found the information [on this post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/#:%7E:text=Example%202%3A%20Execute%20A%20DDL%20Query%20Against%20All%20User%20Databases%20On%20A%20SQL%20Instance)

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb
@command1='IF ''?'' NOT IN (''rdsadmin'', ''master'', ''msdb'', ''model'', ''tempdb'')
BEGIN USE ?
    ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::db_owner TO dbo
    IF EXISTS(select 1 from sys.database_principals where name=''sysuser'')
        DROP USER sysuser
    CREATE USER sysuser from login sysuser;
    ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER sysuser;
    ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER sysuser;
    ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER sysuser;
END'
```